# Active USB VirtualBox XP on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox 5.0.20, and I have a problem with reading USB devices on XP system.

[image]

When I click right and selected "add filter from devices" I show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Add your username to the **vboxusers** group.  One way to do this is by executing `sudo gpasswd -a your_username vboxusers`.
2. Download and install the **VirtualBox 5.0.20 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack** from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).  This will enable full USB support for your vm's.  Double-click on the pack and virtualbox will start and install it.